# is Eclipse RED has feature to search Keywords from imported libraries

Tags: robotframework

I installed Eclipse( Mars ) + RED + RobotFramework-EclipseIDE plugin.
I am writing test scripts in Eclipse.

Earlier i used RIDE to write testcases, there we have Keyword Search functionality to search keywords from the imported libraries.

I want to know, is same functionality exists in Eclipse also?

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: This is available in robotframework plugin :)

Comment: can you please help me, how to use this in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder named "robot-indices" under your project home.
Under "robot-indices" create a file with name "library_name.index"
Add all the keywords which come under your library to this file, one keyword per line.

e.g.

```
<keyword1>
<keyword2>
.... so on
```

Now whenever you open your test file with "robotframework editor" and add below settings

```
*** Settings ***
Library    <Library_name>

*** Test Cases ***
Test Name
    <Cursor here>
```

in your test file. On adding Library reference under setting and hitting "Ctrl + Space" with cursor at that point. You will get a drop down with list of your keywords under that library!

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi waman, my project home is robotFrameWork , under this i created "robot-indices" and then file "Selenium2Library.index" with all the keywords are given as you mentioned but still i am not getting the list, it showing only variables, resources list... can you please help me

Comment: I would need to see your test case file, also index file?

Comment: `*** Settings *** <br/>
Documentation         sample Test Cases<br/>
Library               Selenium2Library<br/>
*** Test Cases ***<br/>
Sample TestCase<br/>
                      Log                  sample testcase`<br/>  This is my test case

Comment: how to add index file here ?

Comment: i installed Luna, but still it is not displaying for me, i updated with new jars, you have given, some issue in setup only i feel

Comment: Hey there is one more possible issue that I might recall from my experience while setting it up. You have to make sure that robot-indices folder exists in the actual workspace (physically) i,e. D:\Workspace\<projectname>\robot-indices\BuiltIn.index should exists!! if you add during java project creation it only links to it (no physical copy will be present).!! do check once

Comment: yes, i have copied physically, it existed in the path `D:\Robot\robotsample\robot-indices' here 'Robot' is workspace folder ; 'robotsample' is project folder